# c++ getline delimiter as any number?

Tags: c++, input, delimiter, getline, istream

I have input in the format of:
`John Smith 2,2 3,1 2,2` and I need to save "John Smith" as one string and then the subsequent numbers into a vector. The issue is, The string part can be any number of words long.

My plan is to use getLine and have the delimiter be 'any number'. Is this possible? I googled but couldn't find anything. Thanks.

Comment: No, delimiter is a single normal character. This is a bad idea.

Comment: Read into a string and search for the first digit.

Comment: Ok. That's a good idea. Thank you.

Also, is there something wrong with how I asked the question? I seem to be getting downvoted. Could it have been worded differently? I'm sorry if I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <locale>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

struct my_punct : std::numpunct<char> {
protected:
    virtual char do_decimal_point() const { return ','; }
    virtual std::string do_grouping() const { return "\000"; } // groups of 0 (disable)
};

struct sName {
    std::string value;
};

static inline void rtrim(std::string &s) {
    s.erase(
        std::find_if(
            s.rbegin(), s.rend(),
            std::not1(std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::isspace))
        ).base(),
        s.end()
    );
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, sName &out)
{
    char ch, last = 0;
    std::ostringstream oss;

    std::istream::sentry s(in);
    if (s)
    {
        out.value.erase();

        do
        {
            ch = in.peek();
            if (!in) break;
            if (std::isspace(last) && std::isdigit(ch)) break;
            ch = in.get();
            oss << ch;
            last = ch;
        }
        while (true);

        out.value = oss.str();
        rtrim(out.value);
    }

    return in;
}
```

```
std::string input = ...; // "John Smith 2,2 3,1 2,2"

sName name;
std::vector<double> v;

std::istringstream iss(input);
iss >> name;
iss.imbue(std::locale(iss.getloc(), new my_punct));
std::copy(
    std::istream_iterator<double>(iss),
    std::istream_iterator<double>(),
    std::back_inserter(v)
);
```